# NSTabView and NSScrollView : Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

The application is developed for macOS with Xcode and swift, programmatically without using storyboard.

It is composed of 4 tabs (raw, synth, fusion, pointage).

It works fine, but one alarm is generated each time we change tab : 
[Layout] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:

Each tab includes NSViewController, NSView, NSScrollView, NSTableView.
For exemple for synth tab :

class GrandLivreSynthesView: NSView, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {

```
private var tableView: NSTableView = NSTableView()
private let scrolView: NSScrollView = NSScrollView()

self.scrolView.documentView = self.tableView
self.addsubview(scrolview)
```

The heights are the same for the 4 tabs; not the widths that are different et probably are the source of the problem.

We add only two constraints on the scrolView :

```
func reloadCell () {

        let metricsDict: [String: CGFloat] = ["width": 1200, "height": 700]
        let viewsDict: [String: NSView] = ["scrolView": scrolView]

        self.removeConstraints(self.constraints)
        self.scrolView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[scrolView(width)]|", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions.alignAllCenterX , metrics: metricsDict as [String : NSNumber]?, views: viewsDict))
        self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[scrolView(height)]|", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions.alignAllCenterX, metrics: metricsDict as [String : NSNumber]?, views: viewsDict))

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Each time we switch from one tab to another one, one alarm is send (without blocking the application) :

```
2017-11-13 15:43:22.381025+0100 DAMOCLES[16696:4950184] [Layout] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000288660 H:|-(0)-[NSScrollView:0x6000001c6720]   (active, names: '|':DAMOCLES.GrandLivreRawView:0x600000183dc0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000002886b0 NSScrollView:0x6000001c6720.width == 920   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000288700 H:[NSScrollView:0x6000001c6720]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':DAMOCLES.GrandLivreRawView:0x600000183dc0 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x600000288980 h=-&- v=-&- DAMOCLES.GrandLivreRawView:0x600000183dc0.minX == 0   (active, names: '|':NSTabView:0x1013d9020 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x6000002889d0 h=-&- v=-&- H:[DAMOCLES.GrandLivreRawView:0x600000183dc0]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':NSTabView:0x1013d9020 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x600000485d70 h=-&- v=-&- DAMOCLES.GrandLivreSynthesView:0x6000001841d0.minX == 0   (active, names: '|':NSTabView:0x1013d9020 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x600000485dc0 h=-&- v=-&- H:[DAMOCLES.GrandLivreSynthesView:0x6000001841d0]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':NSTabView:0x1013d9020 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000029cbb0 H:|-(0)-[NSScrollView:0x6000001c6ae0]   (active, names: '|':DAMOCLES.GrandLivreSynthesView:0x6000001841d0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000029cc50 H:[NSScrollView:0x6000001c6ae0]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':DAMOCLES.GrandLivreSynthesView:0x6000001841d0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000029cc00 NSScrollView:0x6000001c6ae0.width == 1200   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000029cc50 H:[NSScrollView:0x6000001c6ae0]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':DAMOCLES.GrandLivreSynthesView:0x6000001841d0 )>

Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES to have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this happens.  And/or, set a symbolic breakpoint on LAYOUT_CONSTRAINTS_NOT_SATISFIABLE to catch this in the debugger.
```

We don't know how to interpret this : " h=-&- v=-&- ".

If we change the last constraint H:[NSScrollView:0x6000001c6ae0]-(0)-| by H:[NSScrollView:0x6000001c6ae0]-(>=0)-|, the alarm disappears, but the window width doesn't change.

We have tried to analyse with [Debug view hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOpRQ.png), but we are unable to identify which constraint is missing.

We have tried also to add constraints on the TabView but the result is not good.

We could really use some help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What if you do this: `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` for RawView and SynthesView too?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. With your proposal, the window width does not change and the alarm appear once : [Layout] Detected missing constraints for <DAMOCLES.GrandLivreRawView: 0x608000185140>.  It cannot be placed because there are not enough constraints to fully define the size and origin. Add the missing constraints, or set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=YES and constraints will be generated for you. If this view is laid out manually on macOS 10.12 and later, you may choose to not call [super layout] from your override.

Comment: Problem resolved by : 1 reset the size frame of the ScrollView et its superview,  2 Add two constraints to define the size of the superview,   3 modify the 2 constraints of the Scrollview by removing the width et height values.